# "Je veux le lire en française aussi !" vs "Je veux lire en française aussi !"

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

The context of the sentence is that I have read a book in English, and I want to read it in French as well. I would say something like

> "J’adore ce livre! Je veux le lire en française aussi !"

Now I initially write this without the 'le' in 'le lire' but this was corrected to 'le lire'. I am not sure why I cannot just say 'Je veux lire en française aussi !'

Comment: Do you mean that you’re not sure why you can’t say “je veux lire en français aussi”? Your phrasing is a little unclear to me.

Comment: @Maroon yes apologies. Type in the last bit. Fixed now

Comment: Why did you say "I want to read **it** in French" and not "I want to read in French"?

Comment: @LucianSava I want to say 'I want to read it in french'. I didn't realise the 'le' in 'le lire' was acting as 'it'! I thought that is 'ce'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First mistake is :

> lire en française => lire en français

In your case, you have to say it with "le" cause "le" refers to the book you read.

> Je veux le lire en français aussi.

If you say :

> Je veux lire en français aussi.

It means that you want to read in French generally, not specificly this book.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot completely understand your question.

> I've read a book in English. I love it! I  I want to read it in French as well.
>
> J'ai lu un livre en anglais. Je l'adore ! Je veux aussi le lire en français.

There is a clear analogy between French and English here. Your question should have been less unclear. In any case for queries like this [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/I%27ve%20read%20a%20book%20in%20English.%20I%20love%20it!%20I%20I%20want%20to%20read%20it%20in%20French%20as%20well.%0A) comes in handy.